# use of UIpageControl

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uipagecontrol

Can any one explain what is the specific usage of UIPagecontrol in iPhone please.

I am using it for pagination in scroll view. Is there any other specific purpose for it???

Answer (score 0):

Reading documentation for [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) help you to understand uses of pagination.

**Pagination**, which automatically separates the content in your form into smaller groups of rendered content. When you use pagination, these groups of content are automatically formatted to fit the target device. The form also renders user interface (UI) elements that you can use to browse to other pages.

Here is the more simple explanation

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/

Answer (score 0):

You can know how many pages are there and also tapping on it ll navigate to next page.